# Get the last child (if it even) and the prev sibling

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

I have this structure:

```
<div class="as-twl-list-main">
    <div class="as-twl-list-item">

    </div>
    <div class="as-twl-list-item">

    </div>
    <div class="as-twl-list-item">

    </div>
</div>
```

and this scss:

```
.as-twl-list-item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid $as-twl-line-c;

    &:last-child:nth-child(even):nth-child(-1) {
        border-bottom-color: transparent;
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to get the last child (if it even) and the prev sibling.
there is a way to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting the *last child* which is *even* use this:

```
.as-twl-list-item:last-child:nth-child(even) {
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

and for getting the element just before it use [`nth-last-child`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-last-child.asp):

```
.as-twl-list-item:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(odd) {
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

See demo below:

```css
.as-twl-list-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.as-twl-list-item:last-child:nth-child(even) {
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
.as-twl-list-item:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(odd) {
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
Last child even:
<div class="as-twl-list-main">
  <div class="as-twl-list-item">1</div>
  <div class="as-twl-list-item">2</div>
  <div class="as-twl-list-item">3</div>
  <div class="as-twl-list-item">4</div>
</div>

<br/>
Last child odd:
<div class="as-twl-list-main">
  <div class="as-twl-list-item">1</div>
  <div class="as-twl-list-item">2</div>
  <div class="as-twl-list-item">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ZeevKatz let me know your thoughts on this, thanks!

Comment: awesome! works perfect in this way: https://fiddle.jshell.net/m8tbhvx2/

Comment: if you can check my fiddle, maybe you have a better solution, thanks!